# Why did my arduino program suddenly stop working?

Tags: arduino

So I have a project to make for school in which we had to make an arduino project from scratch. I'm relatively new to arduino and his coding and made a simple, yet fun project. I had the idea of making a sort of safe where you have to enter a key and after that, use a potentiometer to make the right combination to open the safe. I don't know what I did wrong but when I uploaded it to my arduino, the program got to the first lines and stopped after printing the first line to the serial monitor. There the program is stuck and doesn't do anything. The weird thing is that it worked 5 minutes ago but now it just wont. Can anyone help me please? My deadline is in a few hours and I can't fix it... Here is the code and a schematic:

[Picture of the setup. The 2 resistors on the left are 1k, the other 2 are 10k.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pmOLz.png)

```
//variabelen
const int pot = A0;
const int pinA = 6;
const int pinB = 5;
const int pinC = 2;
const int pinD = 3;
const int pinE = 4;
const int pinF = 7;
const int pinG = 8;
const int pinP = 9;
const int enter = 11;
const int reset = 12;
byte enterState = 0;
byte lastEnterState = 0;
byte resetState = 0;
byte lastResetState = 0;
int enterTimer = 0;
String wachtwoord;
String ingegeven = "";

//setup
void setup(){
  pinMode(pinA, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(pinB, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(pinC, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(pinD, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(pinE, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(pinF, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(pinG, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(pinP, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(enter, INPUT);
  pinMode(reset, INPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("Geef een wachtwoord op voor de safe.");
  wachtwoord = Serial.read();
}

//eigen methoden


void dispChar(int getal){
  switch(getal){
    case 0:
      digitalWrite(pinA, LOW);   
      digitalWrite(pinB, LOW);   
      digitalWrite(pinC, LOW);   
      digitalWrite(pinD, LOW);   
      digitalWrite(pinE, LOW);   
      digitalWrite(pinF, LOW);   
      digitalWrite(pinG, HIGH);
      break;

    case 1:
      digitalWrite(pinA, HIGH);   
      digitalWrite(pinB, LOW);   
      digitalWrite(pinC, LOW);   
      digitalWrite(pinD, HIGH);   
      digitalWrite(pinE, HIGH);   
      digitalWrite(pinF, HIGH);   
      digitalWrite(pinG, HIGH);
      break;

    case 2:
      digitalWrite(pinA, LOW);   
      digitalWrite(pinB, LOW);   
      digitalWrite(pinC, HIGH);   
      digitalWrite(pinD, LOW);   
      digitalWrite(pinE, LOW);   
      digitalWrite(pinF, HIGH);   
      digitalWrite(pinG, LOW);
      break;

    case 3:
      digitalWrite(pinA, LOW);   
      digitalWrite(pinB, LOW);   
      digitalWrite(pinC, LOW);   
      digitalWrite(pinD, LOW);   
      digitalWrite(pinE, HIGH);   
      digitalWrite(pinF, HIGH);   
      digitalWrite(pinG, LOW);
      break;

    case 4:
      digitalWrite(pinA, HIGH);   
      digitalWrite(pinB, LOW);   
      digitalWrite(pinC, LOW);   
      digitalWrite(pinD, HIGH);   
      digitalWrite(pinE, HIGH);   
      digitalWrite(pinF, LOW);   
      digitalWrite(pinG, LOW);
      break;

    case 5:
      digitalWrite(pinA, LOW);   
      digitalWrite(pinB, HIGH);   
      digitalWrite(pinC, LOW);   
      digitalWrite(pinD, LOW);   
      digitalWrite(pinE, HIGH);   
      digitalWrite(pinF, LOW);   
      digitalWrite(pinG, LOW);
      break;

    case 6:
      digitalWrite(pinA, LOW);   
      digitalWrite(pinB, HIGH);   
      digitalWrite(pinC, LOW);   
      digitalWrite(pinD, LOW);   
      digitalWrite(pinE, LOW);   
      digitalWrite(pinF, LOW);   
      digitalWrite(pinG, LOW);
      break;

    case 7:
      digitalWrite(pinA, LOW);   
      digitalWrite(pinB, LOW);   
      digitalWrite(pinC, LOW);   
      digitalWrite(pinD, HIGH);   
      digitalWrite(pinE, HIGH);   
      digitalWrite(pinF, HIGH);   
      digitalWrite(pinG, HIGH);
      break;

    case 8:
      digitalWrite(pinA, LOW);   
      digitalWrite(pinB, LOW);   
      digitalWrite(pinC, LOW);   
      digitalWrite(pinD, LOW);   
      digitalWrite(pinE, LOW);   
      digitalWrite(pinF, LOW);   
      digitalWrite(pinG, LOW);
      break;

    case 9:
      digitalWrite(pinA, LOW);   
      digitalWrite(pinB, LOW);   
      digitalWrite(pinC, LOW);   
      digitalWrite(pinD, LOW);   
      digitalWrite(pinE, HIGH);   
      digitalWrite(pinF, LOW);   
      digitalWrite(pinG, LOW);  
      break;
  }
}

//Kijk of enter knop is ingedrukt
void onEnter(){
  enterState = digitalRead(enter);
  if(enterState == HIGH){
    enterTimer++;
    if(enterState != lastEnterState){
      ingegeven += map(analogRead(pot), 0, 1023, 0, 9);
      Serial.println(ingegeven);
      enterTimer = 0;
    }
  }
  delay(50); //Voorkomt bounce.
  if(enterTimer > 50){
    Serial.println("\nRESET");
    enterTimer = 0;
    ingegeven = "";
  }
  lastEnterState = enterState;
  check();
}

bool check(){
  if(ingegeven.equals(wachtwoord)){
    return true;
  } else{
    if(ingegeven.length() > wachtwoord.length()){
      Serial.println("FOUT!");
      ingegeven = "";
      return false;
    }
  }
}

//Kijk of reset knop is ingedrukt
void onReset(){
  resetState = digitalRead(reset);

  if(resetState != lastResetState){
    if(resetState == HIGH){
      ingegeven = "";
      Serial.println("Geef een wachtwoord op voor de safe.");
      wachtwoord = Serial.read();

    }
  }
  delay(50); //Voorkomt bounce.
  lastResetState = resetState;
}

//loop
void loop(){
  while(!check()){
    int getal = map(analogRead(pot), 0, 1023, 0, 9);
    digitalWrite(pinP, HIGH);
    dispChar(getal);
    onEnter();
    onReset();
  }
  Serial.println("CODE CORRECT!")
}
```

Thanks for the help!!

[image]

Comment: add more Serial prints to locate the exact line where you get stuck

Comment: Your circuit cartoon doesn't appear to have the right number of resistors to properly drive a 7-segment display.  That's not a StackOverflow question, but an electrical engineering one...

Comment: "code gets stuck" can be a result of RAM overflow. Standard candidates for such disaster are String objects. Can't you have an `int ingegeven` instead?